How can I upload UGC shoes to Roblox without breaking other wearables when moving the Cage.Origin to 0, 0, 0?
I've got a few pairs of shoes I want to upload to the Roblox marketplace. I've created a test pair but this is an issue I'm having across several pairs of shoes. For reference the origin of both cages is set to 0, 0, 0. The origin of the shoe mesh is 0, -0.001661m, -0.02937m. (I’ve tried setting this to 0,0,0 and that doesn’t make a difference.)
Flipflops in Blender
I've imported as fbx into Roblox Studio and set it up as a pants accessory (because there doesn't seem to be an option to upload to the marketplace as a shoe accessory). I've added a WaistCenterAttachment accordingly. At this stage it looks as it should when I test it in game.
Flipflop accessory in Roblox Studio
Flipflops looking correct in-game
When I go to Save To Roblox, and I set the Asset Category to Pants Accessory, I get the following error message: "WrapLayer FlipflopWrapLayer found under Flipflop.Handle has a CageOrigin position greater than 1.50. You need to set CageOrigin.Position to 0,0,0."
Current CageOrigin of FlipflopWrapLayer
So I change the CageOrigin to 0,0,0 and now it breaks any other layered clothing that the avatar is wearing, since the cage tells the mesh how to deform and moving it makes it deform differently than it's supposed to.
Flipflops looking distorted and broken in-game
How can I make the shoes uploadable without breaking the other wearables?
Thank you.
